# Removing mandatory option for image unable to insert the post in mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Hi i am having a page where user can insert the blogs which contains blog name,image and description.Getting the problem while inserting blogs in database.If i am removing the mandatory option for blog image unable to insert  the post into database.It is displaying blog has successfully inserted but there is no blog inserted in my database.

Controller:

```
function addblogs()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error"> ','</span>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('blog_title','Blog Title');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Blog Description');        
    if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)   
    {       
    $data['mainpage']='blogs';
    $data['mode']='add';
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this -> blogs_model -> insertblogs();
        $this->flash->success('<h2>blogs Added Successfully!</h2>');
        redirect('blogs');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
function insertblogs()
{               
    $data=array(        
    'blog_title'=>$this->input->post('blog_title'),
    'description'=>$this->input->post('description'),       
    );
     if ( $_FILES AND $_FILES['image_path']['name'])
            {
                $file_name = $this->do_upload2();
                if(is_array($file_name)){
                    $error['imageerror'] = $file_name['error'];
                }
                else
                $data['image_path']=$file_name;
            }
            if(!isset($data['image_path']) && !isset($error['imageerror']))
            $error['imageerror'] ="Please Upload an image";
            if(isset($error))return $error;     
            $this->db->insert('blogs',$data);

} 

function do_upload2() 
{
    $config = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
        'upload_path' => $this->image_path,
        'max_size' => 20000,
        'maintain_ratio'=>FALSE,
        'width' => 90,
        'height' => 75
    );
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image_path'))
    {
        return $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }
    else
    {
        $image_data = $this->upload->data();
        $config = array(
        'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
        'new_image' =>$this->image_path . '/thumbs',
        'maintain_ratio' => FALSE,
        'width' => 90,
        'height' => 75
        );
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $filename =time().preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\s.\s-]/', '_', $image_data['file_name']);
        rename($image_data['full_path'],$image_data['file_path'].$filename);
        rename($image_data['file_path'].'thumbs/'.$image_data['file_name'],$image_data['file_path'].'thumbs/'.$filename);
        return $filename;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {  
            $('#submit').click(function(){
                    if((jQuery.trim($('#image_path').val())==''))
                    {
                        alert("Please select image");
                        $('#image_path').focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }); 
        </script>           
    <div class="full_w">
    <div class="h_title">
        <div class="lefttitle fl">
            Add Blogs
        </div>
        <div class="rightbutton fr">
            <a  class="button cancel" href="<?php echo site_url()?>/blogs">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        $form_attributes  = array('name'=>'adds', 'id'=>'adds', 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data");
        echo form_open('blogs/addblogs',$form_attributes);
    ?>

    <div class="element">
        <label for="blogtitle"><font color ="black">Blog Title</font></label>
        <input class="text err" type="text" name="blog_title" id="blog_title" value="<?php echo set_value('blog_title');?>"/>               
    </div>          
    <div class="element">
        <label for="description"><font color ="black">Blog Description</font></label>
        <textarea name="description" class="ckeditor" rows="4" cols="173"></textarea>
    </div> <br/>

    <div class="element">
        <label><font color ="black">Select Image:</font></label>
        <input class="err" type="file" name="image_path" id="image_path"/>          
    </div><br/>

    <div align="center">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div> 
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

I am using codeigniter php

Comment: None of your code checks if the operation was actually successful, it just displays "blogs Added Successfully" in all cases. e.g. insertBlogs() can potentially return an error, but the code in addblogs() doesn't check for that. I would guess it's also possible (although I can't see the code so I don't know) that there is the possibility for `$this->db->insert('blogs',$data);` to return or throw an error. You're not checking that either. There's basically no error handling in your code at all.

Comment: @ADyson if i remove the script from view the blog is not inserting into database

Comment: yes you said that already. What's your point? I'm telling you that you need to actually check for errors, which you aren't doing. I can't debug errors that I can't see.

Comment: If i add that script it is working fine

Comment: which bit of script, exactly? There's lots of script in your sample. And please define "working fine". it adds the record to the db?

Comment: I have edited my question deleted other scripts added only one script

Comment: ok so basically you're saying that if you remove a bit of JS that checks if the user has selected an image, it doesn't work. What if you still select an image? Presumably it works then? I guess it only fails if you then don't select an image. That, I would think, is because the PHP code is also checking the same thing inside the insertBlogs function, and returning an error message. But your addblogs() code isn't checking that before naively displaying the "success" message. Which is what I already told you in the first comment. You need to check for errors, very simple.

Comment: Yes if i select image it is adding successfully if there is no image then only it is not inserting

Comment: `if(isset($error))return $error;` this line in insertblogs() is why. It checks for an image, if it doesn't find one, it returns this value instead of doing the insert. But addblogs() never checks the returned value from insertblogs().

Comment: Solved my problem

Comment: glad you did. Thought I was banging my head against a brick wall, I must say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From insert blog section commented three lines now its working fine.

```
if ( $_FILES AND $_FILES['image_path']['name'])
        {
            $file_name = $this->do_upload2();
            if(is_array($file_name)){
                $error['imageerror'] = $file_name['error'];
            }
            else
            $data['image_path']=$file_name;
        }
        //if(!isset($data['image_path']) && !isset($error['imageerror']))
        //$error['imageerror'] ="Please Upload an image";
        //if(isset($error))return $error;
```